# Changing onclick bahavior on laschild

Tags: javascript

I'm very new at this. First question!
I have a FAB button to proceed through a slideshow. The button has a nextSlide function. On the last slide I would like the button to open an html target (another web page).
Here is the pseudo code:

```
function fabTarget() {
var lastSLide = document.getElementById("mySlides").lastChild;
var target = document.getElementById("fab1").onclick.value;
  if lastSlide {
  target = quiz.html;
  else {
  target = plusSlides(1);
  });
```

Can you help me make this succeed? Many thanks

Comment: This is not a code service site. Please explain where you are stuck and why you cant get further?

Comment: How is the slide information held? Is it in an array?

Comment: Orvar. I appreciate your point. I have been going around this for days, and feel I just might not be aiming at the right element in my code.

Comment: Andy. The slides are a series of divs (class="mySlides") inside a div (id="mySlides")